# Copying json doucments from Azure Blob storage To Azure Cosomo Mongo DB Collection using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

> My JSON files(Multiple Files like a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) are in the Azure Blob storage in a folder and I have a Azure Cosmo Mongo DB collections(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k).

> > I want to copy the json file(a) from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Cosmo Mongodb Collection(a) likewise other file's also by Using Terraform.

> > > Can Someone Help me with Terraform sample code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is best suited for resource plan operations, i.e., creating azure resources.

Since what you are looking for is data plane operations, you are better off implementing it in code using the Azure SDKs for [Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#about-blob-storage) and MongoDB for the language you are most familiar with.